# Location and content of telephony.db

Tags: telephony

Can I use SQLite to find the telephony database, `telephony.db`? What tables are stored in this database?

Tried researching in library books, but can't find the list.

Comment: [Telephony content provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony) is an API to the telephony database. While possibly not completely representing the tables and columns, some of the public tables and columns are explained there.

Answer (score 1):

The file `telephony.db` is located in the path `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db`.

Note that this path requires a root permissions (thus a rooted device).

Once you have downloaded the database you can view the content and the database structures (tables, columns, ...) by any SQLite database viewer.

On a rooted device you can access `telephony.db` via file explorer app with root support, or via `adb shell`+ `su`. `adb pull` will not work unless you are running an insecure adb versions which allows `adb root`.

On older Android devices (Android 11 and older) you should be able to get `telephony.db` via `adb backup com.android.providers.telephony` and then extract the created `backup.ab` using [Android Backup Extractor](https://com.android.providers.telephony), a Java based command-line tool.